# Map for O(1) search for both key and value

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, kotlin, hashmap

Consider I have a class:

```
data class User(val userId: String, val roles: List<String>)
```

Also, I have some string `sessionId` and I need `O(1)` time to retrieve data by both `sessionId` and `userId`.

I thought that `BiMap<String, User>` will solve my problem but search by User isn't `O(1)` since I need to cast `User` to `userId` first.

Another solution is to override hashcode/equals for `User` which will take only `userId` into account but it's a dirty hack.

Comment: How about a `Map<String, int>` from `sessionId` to `userId` and a second `Map<int, User>` from `userId` to `User`?

Comment: "search by User isn't O(1) since I need to cast User to userId first." That doesn't make sense. The complexity of a cast is O(1). And having two O(1) operations still makes the entire algorithm O(1) as well.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I need to iterate all elements, cast them (N) and then make a search (1), or am I wrong? Can you elaborate?

Comment: what @ErwinBolwidt said is that what makes your algorithm not constant is not the cast operation, but rather the search itself. I think you were saying the same thing, there was just a misunderstanding

Comment: @user2340612 anyway it's not O(1), isn't it? I think that using two maps is the only way to solve.

Comment: You need to learn more about complexity. Even if you combine one thousand steps sequentially that are each O(1), the resulting algorithm is still O(1).

Comment: Uhm with `BiMap` I think you'll get what you're asking for, since it "maintain two separate maps and keep them both in sync" (from [here](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#bimap)). Since it uses 2 `Map`s, both search by key and by value will be constant (`O(1)`)

Comment: @user2340612 it would work if I won't have object with two fields, can someone of you write it as answer? I don't get how are you going to search by object's field.

Comment: What exactly are your inputs when you want to "search by User" to get a session-id? Is the list of roles a necessary part of the search input? If no, then having a second map from UserId to SessionID is a valid solution. If you like, you can wrap both maps in a facade class which keeps them synchronized. Alternatively, using equals() as you suggested would also be good if it fits the rest of your business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting the `User` to `userId` is `O(1)`. If you are doing complexity analysis you only have to take the term with the largest exponent and drop the rest.

If you perform the same operation 1000 times it will still be `O(1)` if you always do exactly 1000 operations. If the number of operations is constant and does not depend on the size of the input you are having `O(1)` complexity but you have **high constant factors**.

As for your problem:

You can have any number of `Map`s to use as a lookup for your `User`s it will still be `O(1)`:

```
val sessionLookup = mapOf<String, User>()
val userIdLookup = mapOf<String, User>()
```

Here you have two `Map`s which map session ids and user ids to the `User` itself.

What's important here is that you create lookups (eg: a mapping between `userId` - `User` and `sessionId` - `User`) for your `User`s and the operation to **fetch an user by its sessionId or userId** is `O(1)` because you don't have to search. You trade space complexity (the size of the `Map`s) to time complexity (transforming an `O(n)` search to an `O(1)` lookup.

If you really want to get into asymptotic complexity analysis I would suggest [this book](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms-third-edition).

Comment: Indeed, but now problem of synchronization of both map appears, doesn't it?

Comment: This is always a tradeoff. You either do a search `O(n)` or a lookup `O(1)`. Since you already maintain a list of `Users` (I presume) it is not that hard to maintain two `Map`s as well.